# How to call javascript file in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two Layouts and each layout have different **CSS** and **Js** files.
while i use

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

then, it brings all .js files.

Is anything available like following way:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'folder/script1.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'folder/script2.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'folder/script3.js' %> ...
```

Is there a way to only include all scripts in an specific folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new file `application_foo.js` with the following content;

```
//= require_directory folder
```

Add the following line in your second layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application_foo' %>
```

This will include all the javascript files of `folder` directory.

Look at [Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) for more info.