# Calling json.txt files and handling action view controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to RoR and making sample project to learn how JS works in the Rails app using this [little trivia game](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/trivia-game-script_s2).

In case you want it, [relevant code here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lyuuqaz/) for the trivia app.

Now in the ror app, the CSS loads fine because I added the trivia.css.scss file to /stylesheets as well as the Javascript file because I am calling both:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

So far, so good. In Line 347 of trivia.js though, I call the two json.txt files that will be used to populate the test questions:

```
 // Here add pairs with "Category_name" and the file with JSON with quizzes associated to each      
 category 
 var files_json = {'General':'general_json.txt', 'Animals':'animals_json.txt'};
 // calls the method that creates the list with categories for trivia added in JSON
 obTrivia.setCateg(files_json, 'json');
```

Those two files with the test questions are not loading, as the app does not recognize any quiz files. I have two theories about why this is where the trivia game breaks:

1. I am placing the json.txt in the wrong folder and thus it isn't calling correctly. Right now, I am placing in the Javascripts folder because line 347 doesn't call another subdirectory, and my application.html.erb is calling everything in Assets folder already
2. I am totally off base, and I will need to do something with the view controller aspect to tell Rails to parse the JSON files.

Would appreciate feedback on whether I am barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `setCateg` does but generally you would need to include all of your assets and JS files. [Make sure the json files are inside your application and that the folder is getting required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621844/how-to-call-javascript-file-in-ruby-on-rails).

One other observation is that the files passed into `setCateg` are actually text files, perhaps these need to be json files?

Please post some code showing how `setCateg` requires the json files if you need a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, the setCateg comes from the .js file, and it's being set as:  // sets the <select> list with categories, that will be added in #tcateg
  // Receives an object with "category":"file_name" elements, and the type of the files ('xml', or 'json')
  this.setCateg = function(objf, type) {
    objfiles = objf;
    var tcateg = '';  var propf = '';

Comment: Right now, I am storing the the .txt with the trivia questions in the Javascripts folder  of the App > Assets folder because the readme indicated the .txt should be in the same subdirectory as the .js file.

Comment: If you view the page source do you see the `general_json.txt` and `animals_json.txt` along with the other css and js files?